# What is the default load balancing mechanism used by Spring Cloud Eureka and is there a way to modify it?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I understand that Eureka is meant for service discovery, but what if I have multiple instances running for the same service registered in eureka server?

Let's say I have three instances registered in Eureka server for the same service. Then, If I consume the service, I get random instances returned from Eureka.

Does this mean Eureka uses random approach for load balancing? If yes, is it possible to modify it to use round-robin approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default is ribbon and it can be disabled as below

```
spring.application.name=client
spring.cloud.loadbalancer.ribbon.enabled=false
```

this then defaults to  Spring Loadbalancer where you can create custom @LoadBalancerClient and pass your own config

more on it here
https://spring.io/blog/2020/03/25/spring-tips-spring-cloud-loadbalancer